# Is it possible for a sub-directory to be on another server?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, directory

How can I have a sub-directory under a domain point to another server? For example, `example.com/myscript/` should load the script located on a different server than `example.com`. This can be achieved by using a sub-domain, but I need to avoid that.

- `example.com` should load from server 1.
- `example.com/myscript/` should load from server 2.

I am using Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass /myscript http://server2/myscript
ProxyPassReverse /myscript http://server2/myscript
```

[here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) is the apache documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks, will this be SEO friendly and completely transparent to user ?

Comment: i can't answer it for seo, but it is transparent to the user.

Comment: @itech, yes totally SEO friendly